# Owncloud: configuration file config.php absent from the /var/www/owncloud/config/ directory

Tags: raspbian, owncloud

I am trying to install a home cloud storage following [this tutorial](http://www.avoiderrors.net/raspberry-pi-owncloud/).

At a certain step in this tutorial ("Port Forward for External Access"), I have to modify the Owncloud configuration file `/var/www/owncloud/config/config.php`.

Problem: there is no already created `config.php` file in the directory `/var/www/owncloud/config/`. There is only a `config.sample.php` file and another one (`disable-updatechecker.config.php`).

According to [this Owncloud doc](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html), the `config.php` file should have been created during the installation (which I did, because I followed all the previous steps of the above-mentioned tutorial without problem).

How come I don't have the `/var/www/owncloud/config/config.php` file already created? Should I reinstall Owncloud (redo the corresponding step of the tutorial)?

The only thing I did different from the tutorial I mention is that the hard drive I mounted is in `ext4` format, but I doubt this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the ownCloud `config.php` file was absent, but it appeared in `/var/www/owncloud/config/` after I simply updated and upgraded:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```

With this and a `sudo service apache2 restart`, I was able to access the first setup page of my ownCloud.